# Javascript test for picture element or srcset support

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design, modernizr

I would like to upgrade my markup to use the "picture" element, while relying on a responsive images script that I wrote as a fallback.

Is there any way I can conditionally fire my responsive images script only in browsers that do not support the  element?

Modernizr doesn't appear to have this test available until v.3 which is still in beta, so I'm not sure I should be using that in production.

Thank you!

Comment: Just curious. Can't you just use img? I mean, does picture element really add something to your markup semantic wise?

Comment: Indeed I will be using img, but within a picture element, alongside some source tags: check out the picture and srcset implementations in the most recent version of Chrome :) I'm going to be using different images with different art direction at different viewport widths: responsive images now natively supported by Chrome.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/images/images-in-markup?hl=en

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modernizr 3 is not really beta. Its just waiting on us to finish writing some of the stuff for the website. That being said, you can totally just grab the detects from the v3 source and add them to your 2.x version, like so for the picture element

`Modernizr.addTest('picture', 'HTMLPictureElement' in window );`

and for src-set...

`Modernizr.addTest('srcset', 'srcset' in document.createElement('img'));`

and you are off to the races.

Comment: Thank you! Glad to hear v3 will be officially launched soon :)  I will add that lovely bit of code to my modernizr 2 file and that should do me right.